# AIX 7.1 Create another user with equal privileges as root and then disable root user

Tags: passwords, root, aix

I've got a weird, stupid question. I've used linux for a long time, but I know AIX is different in certain places, so my question is if I wanted to disable the root user at least from remote login I could, but can I create another user with equal privileges to use instead of root? 
Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any other UNIX you can edit /etc/passwd and change the UID and GID of any other user to 0. This de facto creates a second root user. Depending on your remote access method you can then disable root login by explicitly prohibiting the "root" user, do not block all root users with some global method.

But seriously, use `sudo`. AIX knows that also.